# Laravel query builder where condition from relationship table

Tags: laravel

I have following tables

**Messages**:

- user_id
- group_id
- text
- created_at

And
**group_users**:

- user_id
- left_at
- group_id

These tables have relationship via "group_id".

I need "Messages" that created before "group_user" left group.
In other word, i need a query like this:

`$messages = Message::where('created_at','<',group_user.left_at)->get();`
How can i achieve this?

Comment: By [join](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins)-ing the other table using the `group_id`?

Comment: what about if a user has not left the group? you need the messages of a user before user left the group?

Comment: Rule is: if user still in the group, all messages has to be loaded. Once user left the group, user can view messages that before he left.

Answer (score 0):

it can be like the code below(untested):
in the Message model

```
public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}
```

in the controller

```
$messages = Message::whereHas('group', function($q){
                            $q->where('left_at','>','messages.created_at');
                       })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this assuming you have the user ID at hand:

```
Message::join('group_users', 'messages.group_id', '=', 'group_users.group_id')
    ->where('group_users.user_id', $id)
    ->where('group_users.left_at', '>', 'messages.created_at')
    ->get();
```